# Generate Xml from Xsd with ado.net

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, ado.net

I want to generate xml from a xsd, this xml I want to contain specify attributes from xsd. Any ideas?

```
string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Data") + "\\" + fn;
    try
    {
        File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
        Response.Write("The file has been uploaded.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        //Note: Exception.Message returns a detailed message that describes the current exception. 
        //For security reasons, we do not recommend that you return Exception.Message to end users in 
        //production environments. It would be better to put a generic error message. 
    }
    try
    {
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(SaveLocation);
        //XmlSchema myschema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, ValidationCallback);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           // LiteralURL.Text += reader.ReadString();
        }
        // Response.Write("\t"+myschema.Items);
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(SaveLocation);
        var ListNode = new List<XNode>();
        if (doc != null)
        {
            Response.Write("nu este null");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Null !");
        }
        int i = 0;
       string str = "";
        foreach (XNode nodes in doc.Elements())
        {

            str = "node1:  " + nodes.ToString();
            ListNode[i] = nodes;
            i++;

        }

       for(int j = 0; j < i; i++)
        {
            Response.Write("FirstNode:"+ ListNode[j]);

        }
        //Response.Write("FirstNode:" );
        Response.Write(str);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

}
else
{
    Response.Write("Please select a file to upload.");
}
```

Comment: This is poor content. Unreadable and probably too broad. Please read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at xsd.exe. You run this against your XSD and it gives you classes based on the XSD elements and attributes. You don't need to work with raw XML or XSD after that.